# How to combine 2 methods from 2 classes derived from 1 base?

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, abstract, chess

I'm creating a chess game, I already created the rook's and the bishop's and I'm about to start creating the queen piece. The problem is that the queen combines the moves of the rook's and the bishop's, so I don't want to write repetitive code and instead just use the 2 classes for the rook's and the bishop's and they're methods into the queen one.

Here's the bishop class

```
public class OficerPiece : Figure
{
    public OficerPiece(FigureDefinition definition) : base(definition)
    {
    }

    protected override List<Tuple<int, int>> GetValidTurns()
    {
        //here i set the valid moves
    }
}
```

The rook class is basically the same but with different implementation of the `GetValidTurns()`

Every single piece in my project inherits the `Figure` abstract class which contains info that every piece is using the only difference is in the `GetValidTurns` method so we leave that for the derived class to implement.

That's the queen class

```
public class Kralica : Figure
{
    public Kralica(FigureDefinition definition) : base(definition)
    {
    }

    protected override List<Tuple<int, int>> GetValidTurns()
    {
        //here i want to combine the 2 methods GetValidTurns from the bishop class and the rook class
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new class or interface for your valid turns to encapsulate them and make it easy to reuse.

```
public interface ValidTurn
{
    List<Tuple<int, int>> GetValidTurns();
}

public class StraightSlide : ValidTurn
{
    public List<Tuple<int, int>> GetValidTurns()
    {
         // ... valid rook turns here
    }
}

public class DiagonalSlide : ValidTurn
{
    public List<Tuple<int, int>> GetValidTurns()
    {
         // ... valid bishops turns here
    }
}

public class Kralica : Figure
{
    public Kralica(FigureDefinition definition) : base(definition)
    {
    }

    protected override List<Tuple<int, int>> GetValidTurns()
    {
        var straight = new StraightSlide();
        var diagonal = new DiagonalSlide();

        return straight.Concat(diagonal);
    }
}
```

Also the code in your original classes should be replaced by your new ValidTurn classes.

**Edit:**

```
public class StraightSlide : ValidTurn
{
    private Figure figure;
    public StraightSlide(Figure figure)
    {
        this.figure = figure;
    }

    public List<Tuple<int, int>> GetValidTurns()
    {
         figure.YourMethodToCall();
         // ... valid rook turns here
    }
}
```

You could maybe consider put all your validation logic into the ValidTurn(TurnValidation).

Comment: I cant implement the valid rook turns for example there because they must also inherit from the `Figure` class because it contains essential functions to check if a turn is valid.

Comment: You can pass the Figure class with the ValidTurns constructor or with the function parameters. And maybe you want to put the other logic of your turn validation also in this ValidTurn class (see single responsibility principle).

Comment: Can you edit your answer so you can show me how to do that ? I'm talking about the constructor with the parameter

Answer (score 2):

You could perhaps come at this a different way.

Have an abstract base class that defines a move:

```
public abstract class Move
{
    // Whatever
}
```

And then derive different moves from that, for example:

```
public sealed class Diagonal : Move // Bishop, Queen
{
}

public sealed class Orthongonal : Move // Rook, Queen
{
}

public sealed class KnightsMove : Move
{
}

public sealed class KingsMove : Move
{
}
```

Then you can combine the different moves using composition:

```
public class Kralica : Figure
{
    public Kralica(FigureDefinition definition) : base(definition)
    {
    }

    protected override List<Move> GetValidTurns()
    {
        return moves;
    }

    readonly List<Move> moves = new List<Move> {new Diagonal(), new Orthongonal()};
}
```

Your `Move` class might be declared as follows:

```
public abstract class Move
{
    public abstract IEnumerable<Position> PossibleMoves(Position start, Board board);
}
```

where `Position` is another class defined to hold information about a position on the board (which may be as simple as just X, Y coords), and `Board` is a class which holds information about where all the pieces are on the board.

Then an implementation of `PossibleMoves()` would return an enumeration of all the possible moves for that type starting from the given position and with the board in the given state.

Comment: This seems pretty neat but I'm beginner and im not quite sure what should i put in the abstract class Move. If you can provide some sample code maybe using a virtual methods :? Because as far as i understand the sealed classes will have only 1 method in them and that's it nothing else so why not make them into methods themselfs ?

Comment: Sealed only prevents inheritence and you would split it up so you can reuse your turn code (as you wish to do). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle

Comment: I know what sealed class does i meant that they will contain only 1 method whatsoever

Comment: Yea but that is no issue infact it is good practice (see single responsibility principle). Also you dont know maybe later you'll add something?

Comment: @PreqlSusSpermaOhranitel I can't really tell you what to put into the `Move` implementations because I don't know how the rest of your code is structured. The main point is that you encapsulate the logic to do with a move in a separate class. My suggestion is more of a general concept than a concrete implementation.

Answer (score 0):

If you're a beginner why not put some simple methods in your base class Figure that adds moves to your point list?

```
    public class Kralica : Figure
    {
        protected Tuple<int, int> Position {get; set;}

        public Kralica(FigureDefinition definition) : base(definition)
        {
        }

        protected override List<Tuple<int, int>> GetValidTurns()
        {
            //here i want to combine the 2 methods GetValidTurns from the bishop class and the rook class
        }

        protected void AddDiagonalMoves(List<Tuple<int, int>> moves)
        {
            diagonalMoves = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();

            // calculate diagonal moves from my piece position which should be a member property here

            moves.AddRange(diagonalMoves);
        }
    }


public class Kralica : Figure
{
    public Kralica(FigureDefinition definition) : base(definition)
    {
    }

    protected override List<Tuple<int, int>> GetValidTurns()
    {
        var movesThisTurn = new List<Tuple<int, int>>(); 
        //here i want to combine the 2 methods GetValidTurns from the bishop class and the rook class
        base.AddDiagonalMoves(movesThisTurn);
        base.AddLinearMoves(movesThisTurn);

    }
}
```

Then your derived classes could just re-use those methods inside their respective GetValidTurns building the list of moves to return.

Editorial: Even if you're a beginner I recommend getting away from the Tuple here and creating a simple "point" class or struct. It will make your code much more readable, even for yourself.

Comment: But implementing this as static functions may be not the best oop practice. But i agree with you the Tuples maybe better would be something like "bool IsValidTurn(Figure figure, int x, int y)"

Comment: These wouldn't be static functions but protected methods inside your figure base class. Reusing base class functionality isn't bad OOP. You would essentially be detaching the valid moves away from the individual pieces into a more generic approach. You could model it in more complex ways certainly, but this isn't a list of static methods :)

Comment: Ok this looks better but also there is the Figure and turn validation in one class and this kind of violates the single responsibility principle?

Comment: If you're concerned about SRP you can certainly extract this into another class FigureMoves which Figure uses. Sorry, was trying to keep it simple. FigureMoves would then simply need an extra parameter for the piece's current position.

Comment: No problem and i totally understand you i only insisted on it cause to me seamed like the root of his problem. So dont worry about it :D